# Input value returning [object Object] using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using jQuery in asp.net to assign the value to a hidden field (hfstockcode). But it is returning [object Object]. When I print the value in console it is showing v.fn.v.init[1]. How can I get the value in the hidden field.

```
$(document).on("change", '.stockcode', function () {
    var fieldid = $(this).attr('data-fieldid');
    alert(fieldid);
    var stock = $('#field_iditem' + fieldid + '').val();
    alert(stock);
    var hai = $('#hfstockcode').val(stock);
    //console.log(hai);
    alert(hai);
}); 

var fName1 = $('<div class="col-md-2"> <input type="text" placeholder="Item" data-fieldid="' + intId + '"  id="field_iditem' + intId + '"  name="field_item"  class="form-control stockcode"></div>');
```

My hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfstockcode" runat="server" />
```

Comment: `var hai = $('#hfstockcode').val(stock)` is invoking the setter form of `val()`, not its getter form. After that call, `hai` will be the jQuery object returned by `$('#hfstockcode')`, not the value of its underlying DOM element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setter version of .val() return a jQuery object that is why you are getting [Object object] when you alert `hai`.

If you want to get the value of the hidden field, you need to use the getter version of .val()

```
$(document).on("change", '.stockcode', function () {
    var fieldid = $(this).attr('data-fieldid');
    alert(fieldid);
    var stock = $('#field_iditem' + fieldid + '').val();
    alert(stock);
    $('#hfstockcode').val(stock);
    var hai = $('#hfstockcode').val();
    //console.log(hai);
    alert(hai);
});
```